# Where does opendj stores invalid login attempt count of a user and Is it accessible?

Tags: ldap, opends, opendj

Is it possible in opendj to check how many failed attempts has been done by a user so that based on that I can display some captcha before account lockout.

Answer (score 0):

OpenDJ doesn't store a counter but has an operational attribute in each entry that contains the recent failure times: pwdFailureTime.
Alternate, there's a command line utility that can report the status of any account : manage-account.

Regards,

Ludovic.

Comment: Thanks Ludo, I was aware of pwdFailureTime attribute but my requirement is to display the captcha just one count less than the account lockout attempt. i.e. if lockout count is 5 then after 4th attempt I should display captcha to user. In that case may be I need to store and reset the counter manually somewhere. Any alternate suggestion is appreciated. But can you also confirm if the counter value can be checked by any means to know how many wrong attempts has been done by a user?

Comment: I know I'm replying a bit late... but this could be helpful to somebody else: you can count how many pwdFailureTime there are and that's the amount of failed attempts.

Answer (score -1):

When you enable password policy at opendj, opendj adds an attribute out of the box that keeps track of the invalid attemps.

The parameter name is “sunAMAuthInvalidAttemptsData” , it stores a json object that has other information including “InvalidCount”. It appears as soon as you enable account lockout feature at OpenDJ.

Comment: sunAMAuthInvalidAttemptsData is an attribute set by AM, not openDJ